# Node JS Can't set headers after they sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, header

I'm writing a node js application. For some reason, I can load the page once, it works. Then after that I get an error saying "Can't set headers after they are sent"

Any help woud be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
module.exports = {

login: function(req, res) {

    login.parseLogin(function(status) {

        if(status != true) {
            res.end();
        }

        res.send('{"Success": ' + true + '}');
        res.end();

    }, "Robert", "C");

},

signup: function(req, res) {

    signup.parseSignup(function(status) {

        if(status != true) {
            res.send(' {"Failed to create account": ' + new Date() + '} ');
            res.end();
        }

        res.send(' {"Account": ' + username + ',"createdAt": ' + new Date() + '} ');
        res.end();

    });

},


addbit: function(req, res) {
    console.log("Addbit");
},


removeBit: function(req, res) {
    console.log("RemoveBit");
},

queryBits: function(req, res) {
    console.log("QueryBits");
}

};
```

Comment: Try using `return res.send()`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in both your login and signup functions is that you check for an error condition, end the response and then go ahead and send a response again.

```
    if(status != true) {
        res.end();
    }
```

should be

```
   if(status != true) {
        return res.end();
    }
```

In one or more of those functions the first time you load the page the value is true and the next time it's false.

And in signup, it should be:

```
if(status != true) {
        res.send(' {"Failed to create account": ' + new Date() + '} ');
        return res.end();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You either stop the execution after the if statement or you could simply add an else clause:

```
 if(status != true) {
            res.send(' {"Failed to create account": ' + new Date() + '} ');
        } else {
            res.send(' {"Account": ' + username + ',"createdAt": ' + new Date() + '} ');
        }
 res.end();
```